# How to dinamically set querySelector to read all elements of a header?

Tags: loops, dom, jquery-selectors

I'm pretty basic on querySelector, so I excuse me if my question is pretty basic but I'm not able to find the solution online

Basically i'm trying to set the width of a table header based on the width of the cell under it

The code i did until now is this :

```
var headerElement = elem.querySelector('thead tr:first-child th:first-child');
var rowElement = elem.querySelector ('tbody tr:first-child td:first-child');

headerElement.style.width = (rowElement.scrollWidth) + 'px';
```

what i want to achieve/understand is how to dinamically loop through all "headers object" in that table and using the same "index" to iterate the row under to have something like this:

```
while (headerElements > i){
var headerElement = elem.querySelector('thead tr:first-child th:i');
    var rowElement = elem.querySelector ('tbody tr:first-child td:i');

    headerElement.style.width = (rowElement.scrollWidth) + 'px';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it this way:

```
var header = elem.querySelector('thead tr:first-child');
var row = elem.querySelector ('tbody tr:first-child');
for (i=0;header.cells.length > i;i++){
    header.cells[i].style.width = (row.cells[i].scrollWidth) + 'px';
}
```